# Wordpress: Content Visibility set to Private and Cant Change it to Public

Tags: wordpress, themes

I got a Wordpress site with a theme from ColorLabs (already wrote to them that they take days to answer here is quicker), and I don't know why but all the posts are set to private by default, and of course I know in order to change it I have to go below the Publish button and change it to Public, but even if I do that, after I refresh the page it defaults back to Private.

Also I don't have any plugins installed that set content to private. Anyone has this problem before, where on the code or files is that visibility or status function so I can put it back to Public as it should be as default. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This might be different for your theme, but [this](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-set-new-post-visibility-to-private-by-default#post-1508678) post might work:

Edit the `meta-boxes.php` file located in the `wp-admin/includes/` folder and change

```
} else {    
$visibility = 'private';
$visibility_trans = __('Private');
```

to the following:

```
} else {
$visibility = 'public';
$visibility_trans = __('Public');
```

Comment: Thanx but it is set to public on these file, it must on the somewhere colorlabs theme configuration, i got to find a file like meta-boxes.php but on the goodliving colorlabs theme, cause i noticed that the pages, posts, are all set to public, only the property posts of the colorlabs theme framework are set to private. I all have to wait for the colorlabs guys to reply or someone who has used this theme before, or if if u want to see the theme i can send u the colorlabs theme, its premium. Thanx Anyways!